# Rearranging array after opening a CSV file with Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

With my script I'm getting a list of all my installed apps on my pc, including their version. As I save it into a csv file and open it with Excel it does not list them per row, instead it lists all of them within a single row (cell). How can I rearrange my array, list of apps, so it sorts them singularly into each row (cell) of the column.

```
$currentUsername = $env:USERNAME
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$timeStamp = Get-Date -Format "ss-mm-HH-dd/MM/yyyy"
$desktopPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:USERPROFILE, 'Desktop')
$outputFileName = "${timeStamp}_${currentUsername}_${computerName}.csv"
$outputFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($desktopPath, $outputFileName)

$installedApps = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ne $null }
$installedAppsList = $installedApps | ForEach-Object {"$($_.DisplayName) ($($_.DisplayVersion))"}


$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Installierte Anwendungen"  = $installedAppsList -join ", "
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation  -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Try `,` instead of `;`. CSV is a text file, not an Excel format. The standard separator is `,` (hence Comma-Separated), not ';`. BUT, as roughly half of the world uses `,` as the decimal separator, a *lot* of applications and scripts use different separators. Excel will use the locale's list separator setting when you double-click on a CSV file

Comment: If you really need an Excel file, check [Export and import to and from Excel with the PowerShell module ImportExcel](https://4sysops.com/archives/export-and-import-to-and-from-excel-with-the-powershell-module-importexcel/). This adds an `Export-Excel` command that creates real `xlsx` files using the EPPlus library

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it :

```
$currentUsername = $env:USERNAME
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$timeStamp = Get-Date -Format "ss-mm-HH-dd/MM/yyyy"
$desktopPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:USERPROFILE, 'Desktop')
$outputFileName = "${timeStamp}_${currentUsername}_${computerName}.csv"
$outputFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($desktopPath, $outputFileName)

$installedApps = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -ne $null }
$installedAppsList = $installedApps | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion

$installedAppsList | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation  -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this was a long and helpful answer! very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting all values in a single cell is because you are creating a PSCustomObject with 1 property, and you are setting that property to be a string containing the entire contents of your variable `$installedAppsList`.

This is happening in this portion of your code:

```
$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "Installierte Anwendungen"  = $installedAppsList -join ", "
}
```

Instead you can do this:

```
$installedAppsList | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Installierte Anwendungen' | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation  -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

Opening the resulting file in Excel, you will see that you now have a single column named 'Installierte Anwendungen' with each value in its own cell in that column.

Or you can skip the need to use `ConvertFrom-Csv` by doing this:

```
$installedAppsList = $installedApps | ForEach-Object { New-Object psobject -Property @{'Installierte Anwendungen' = "$($_.displayName) $($_.displayVersion)"}}
```

In the second example we are creating `$installedAppsList` as an array of psobjects, where the psobject has a property named `Installierte Anwendungen`.

Here is some more information about what is happening here:
It is important to keep in mind that the various CSV related cmdlets are designed to work with objects and their properties. For example, when the psobject `$data` is created it has a single property named 'Installierte Anwendungen' and the value of that property is a string containing all of your data. When passed to `Export-Csv`, that cmdlet sees the named property and its string value.

The same is true with the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet. If you pass `$installedAppsList` to `ConvertTo-Csv` you will see that the output is the length of each string contained in the variable. This is because the cmdlet sees that the variable contains string objects, and those string objects have a single property named length. To see this for yourself, pass a string to `Get-Member` cmdlet.

The key is to get your data into a format where it consists of objects that have named properties whose values are the data you want in your output. The convertFrom-Csv can do this for you. In this particular case you must include the `-header` parameter. If this is not included then the first value in your array will be treated as a header. After doing this you will have an array of psobjects where each object has a property named 'Installierte Anwendungen' whose value is a string.

At that point you can send that array of psobjects to the Export-Csv cmdlet and it will correctly see that you want a single column named 'Installierte Anwendungen' with each index of the array becoming a single cell in your output.